# Can anyone see why Tomcat is timing out on my connection pool?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, connection-pooling

have a connection pool in my Springboot App with these settings in Application.properties:

```
// db user name, password, url here...
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=100
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=8
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
```

All is OK for a while. But what's happening is that every few hours, something goes wrong and I get this Exception when trying to run the JDBC code:
Unexpected end of data.

In other classes, the Unexpected end of data Exception shows up as a SQL Exception, but it's the same message.

If I restart Tomcat, JDBC is all working again ... for a little while.

The Connection code looks like this:

```
try
    (
            final Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_TO_RUN_HERE);
    )
    {
    .
    .
    .
    
    }
```

"dataSource" is injected into the class and is the Connection Pool instance.

Also, if I don't use the connection pool at all and just use `DriverManager.getConnection(...),` it always works then too with no problems.

### Additional debugging info:

SQL State: 08007
Detail Message: [FileMaker][FileMaker JDBC] Unexpected end of data.
Error code: 27026

Line of code that fails: connection.prepareStatement(SQL)

Can anyone see what setting is off or what setting I might need to add to the connection pool settings?

Thanks very much in advance,

Comment: Running out of connections in a pool is annoying, but it's not "unexpected end of data". Maybe you're doing something weird, sharing a connection accidentally or an internal bug that manifests in your use case.

Comment: Please share the database type and version of the driver. Please also share the part of the log files preceding the exception and full stack trace. It would be helpful to set the log level to debug for the interesting packages like `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool`

Comment: Interesting....how to you go about setting the log level for the pool? Also, maybe there's a way I can get more detailed logging info. Thanks!

Comment: Add to application.properties: logging.level.org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool=DEBUG

Comment: Nice! That's great, I think this will be very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Try increasing the max-active value, as a value of 100 might be too low depending on your application's concurrency requirements

Comment: Won't that time out again at some point though? It's really just a couple users at the moment using this database.

Comment: We can play with values to identify the problem, my first thought is this max-active value, however if you are saying now that there are only a few users, the problem might be with min/max idle

Comment: Have a read about [connection pool sizing](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing).

Comment: So, if there are a couple users and it seems that the connection pool "times out" after a couple hours (not sure exactly what's happening, actually), what kind of value do you think would be appropriate as a test fro min/max idle? Thanks.